# Camel consumer route with input from another consumer route

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel, paho, spring-camel

I have a kafka consumer route from where I get some data.

```
from("Kafka:foo?brokers=localhost:9092")
```

Once I receive data from the consumer, use that data in the topic name for a paho mqtt consumer.

```
from("paho:#?brokerUrl=tcp://localhost:1883")
```

I'm not able to figure out how to set the dynamic header CamelMqttTopic, from first consumer, as both seems independent flows. I'm using camel with Spring framework. Excuse me if my basic camel understanding is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the *MQTT* topic using the `CamelPahoOverrideTopic` message header with a value being the *Kafka* topic accessed through the `kafka.TOPIC` message header:

```
from("kafka:foo?brokers=localhost:9092")
    .setHeader(PahoConstants.CAMEL_PAHO_OVERRIDE_TOPIC, simple("${headers[kafka.TOPIC]"))
    .to("paho:#?brokerUrl=tcp://localhost:1883");
```